# new PropertyMetadata(0.0,OnAngleChanged) vs new PropertyMetadata(0,OnAngleChanged)

Tags: c#, wpf

Follow is CSharp code, and I want to use the attached property `Angle` to change the rectangles' angle in my XAML. The problem is when I change the `new PropertyMetadata(0.0,OnAngleChanged)` to`new PropertyMetadata(0,OnAngleChanged)` then it doesn't work and throw `XamlParseException` and says that `the type initializer for XXX.RotationManager threw an exception`. I wonder why `new PropertyMetadata(0,OnAngleChanged)` does't work.

```
class RotationManager
{
    public static double GetAngle(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(AngleProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAngle(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AngleProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(RotationManager), new PropertyMetadata(0.0,OnAngleChanged));

    private static void OnAngleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as UIElement;
        if (element!=null)
        {
            element.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(.5, .5);
            element.RenderTransform = new System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform((double)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PropertyMetadata first constructor argument is of type object. If you only write 0 then it will be interpreted as int type and get boxed. Try new PropertyMetadata( (double)0, ... ) to state you want a double value

Comment: thank you so much, it really solve my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the first parameter of `PropertyMetaData()` is the same type as `GetAngle` and `SetAngle`, when you change the type of `GetAngle` and `SetAngle` to `int`, and the `new PropertyMetadata(0,OnAngleChanged)` can work.

---

However, changing the property type to `int` isn't feasible. It should have the same type as the property that it is assigned to later, i.e. `RotateTransform.Angle`, which is `double`.

The best solution would be to *not specify a default value at all*, and thus implicitly get `0.0` or `default(double)` as default value:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Angle", typeof(double), typeof(RotationManager),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAngleChanged)));
```

Comment: I try your method, it is better answer than Sir Rufo's answer

Comment: Changing the property type is the wrong approch. An angle should be represented by a floating point type, typically `double`.